# Moving the view area when a button is clicked

Tags: leaflet

I'm pulling my hair out over this one!

I've got a map that loads when a button is clicked, I'd like it to then move the map to a new area when one of the other buttons is clicked. However if another button is clicked I get the error 'Map container is already initialized.'

I tried adding a condition in there that pans to a new loctation if the map has already been loaded, but then I get 'Cannot read property 'panTo' of undefined'!

This is how the map loading function looks:

```
function getMap(selectedArea) {
if ( mapLoaded ) {
    map.panTo(selectedArea, 10);
} else {
    $('#map').show();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height () }, 'slow')

    var map = L.map('map').setView(selectedArea, 10);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    mapLoaded = true;
}
```

The selectedArea just returns an array of coordinates like [33.843970009, -118.170583372] based on the users button click, and the mapLoaded is a global function is set to false at pageload.

Any thoughts?

Thanks very much!

Tayler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing works perfectly? Just as long as you make sure that the variables defining the map and loaded flag are declared outside of the function your using to create or pan the map:

```js
var map, loaded, coordinates = [[-25, -25], [-25, 25], [25, -25], [25, 25]];

function getMap(coordinate) {
    if (loaded) {
        map.panTo(coordinate, 2);
    } else {
        map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
            'center': coordinate,
            'zoom': 2,
            'layers': [
                new L.TileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
                })
            ]
        });
        loaded = true;
    }
}

L.DomEvent.addListener(L.DomUtil.get('button'), 'click', function () {
    getMap(coordinates[Math.floor(Math.random() * coordinates.length)]);
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#leaflet {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button">Change coordinate</button>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe there is something else in your code messing with the `map` or `mapLoaded` variables?

FYI: You don't have to set/use a flag to mark loaded you can just check if the `map` variable holds an instance of `L.Map` using the `instanceof` operator:

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

```
var map, coordinates = [[-25, -25], [-25, 25], [25, -25], [25, 25]];

function getMap(coordinate) {
    if (map instanceof L.Map) {
        map.panTo(coordinate, 2);
    } else {
        map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
            'center': coordinate,
            'zoom': 2,
            'layers': [
                new L.TileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
                })
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You were right, I was just being dense. I was declaring my map in the wrong place.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.